# How to build Android-x86 using the LineageOS codebase as a starting point?

Tags: android, git, build, android-source, repo

I already have a directory with the entire source code for LineageOS, which was initialized with:

```
repo init -u https://github.com/LineageOS/android.git -b lineage-15.1
```

After a couple builds, the directory is over 70GiB.

Now I would like to build Android-x86 (the LineageOS branch/port), and I'd like to know if there's a way to "rebase" the existing source code instead of re-downloading it all over again.

The Android-x86 code base is initialized with

```
repo init -u git://git.osdn.net/gitroot/android-x86/manifest -b oreo-x86
```

I tried running this from the same directory but got as a result:

> fatal: manifest 'default.xml' not available
>   fatal: remote github not defined in /media/Fast/Dev/android/lineage/.repo/manifests/default.xml

I checked that `.repo/manifests/default.xml` exists in the file system, and is identical to another one created by `repo init` to a new directory.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run on my computer due to the size but I guess the solution could be:

On LineageOS `manifest.xml` add a line at the end with `<include name="android-x86.xml" />` and also copy the `android-x86.xml` from the android oreo project to the `manifests` folder in the LineageOS project.

After run `repo sync` it should keep the LineageOS but download the x86 part of the Android and add/override what is necessary. Not sure if gonna work though.

This is how it looks before changes:
[image]

After the changes on LineageOS Manifest.xml and add to Manifests folders:
[image]

Unfortunately I can't test but that is the idea. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I didn't need to add the `<include>` line suggested by you because it was already there. I also checked the file `android-x86.xml` from the Android-x86 repo and it was bit identical to that in the LineageOS repo. Upon running `repo sync` I got an error message quite similar to the one mentioned in my question - *"fatal: remote github not defined in /media/Fast/Dev/android/lineage/.repo/manifest.xml"*.

Comment: Ah, I think I'm on to something. I renamed the `.repo` directory and ran `repo init (...)` again and maybe this will work. Unfortunately I just ran out of disk space as well :( but give me a few days and I'll get another hdd.

Comment: Would be nice if I could show you but what I did I create two separate folders (oreo and lineageos). Inside lineageos, I run repo init lineage command and I notice that my Manifest.xml doesn't have the android-x86 part. Then I switch to oreo folder and run the second command and I can see the manifest in the oreo folder with android-x86 addons. if you run both repo init on the same folder, it will overrride the entire x-86 over the lineageos. Run both in separate folders, then copy the x-86 to the lineageos, add the include and run repo sync in the lineageos. May be this.